# Is there a commonly-used filename extension for unified diff format?

Tags: diff, patch

E.g. `.difffile`, `.diff`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

actually most programmers use .patch and sometimes .diff

Answer (score 4):

I've seen both .diff and .patch, but the most common practice seems to be having no filename extension except for the compression (usually .gz or .bz2). At least that's how it's done for the [linux kernel](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/).