# Git: How to diff two different files in different branches?

Tags: git, git-diff

I have two different files in different branches.
How can I diff them in one command?

Something like

```
# git diff branch1/foo.txt branch2/foo-another.txt
```

I could check out the other file, diff it and restore, but that's quite dirty solution.

Comment: @EugenKonkov It's not a duplicate because this question is asking how to diff **different files** in different branches.  The linked question only asks how to diff the **same file** in different branches.

Comment: [If one or both files is in the working tree (file system), consider this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683121/git-diff-between-two-different-files)

Answer (score 285, accepted):

```
git diff branch1:full/path/to/foo.txt branch2:full/path/to/foo-another.txt
```

You can also use relative paths:

```
git diff branch1:./relative/path/to/foo.txt branch2:./relative/path/to/foo-another.txt
```

Comment: Awesome! I was certainly not able to infer that from `git help diff`. By the way, those don't have to be branch names ahead of the colons, but can be any kind of commit references (e.g. SHA-1 values).

Comment: Important Note: Git on windows requires the full itemspec to be a unix name. i.e. branch1:full\path\to\foo.txt fails, while branch1:full/path/to/foo.txt works fine, as does full\path\to\foo.txt (no branch)

Comment: use `git difftool` and then drop the `branch2:` and that will allow you to edit a file in the current working tree (to bring over changes from `branch1`)

Comment: Tried on linux with git version 1.8.3.1, only relative paths allowed.

Answer (score 25):

Sidenote: no need for full paths, you can start with `./` for relative paths. It can be handy sometimes.

```
git diff branch1:./relative/path/to/foo.txt branch2:./relative/path/to/foo-another.txt
```

Answer (score 12):

**Off-topic answer -- diffing the *same* file in different branches**

Just to add it for I find it a very straightforward syntax :

```
git diff <branch1> <branch2> <filepath>
```

Also works with relative refs like for example :

```
# compare the previous committed state from HEAD with the state branch1 was 3 commits ago
git diff HEAD^ <branch1>~3 <filepath>
```

Comment: The OP specifically asked for "different files". Your answer is about comparing the same file in two different branches.

Comment: @EtienneMiret You're absolutely right, I missed that important point. Off-topic answer.

Comment: Still, many people land on this question because they want to get the difference for the same file, and this answer is useful.

Comment: @Matthieu Then why not link to a relevant answer rather?

Comment: @jtlz2 I'm not sure I understand. This answer *is* relevant for that problem (albeit not the OP). The cause is Google that lands us here ;)

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to compare files from two diferents branchs. For example:

- If the name is the same or different:

  ```
   git diff branch1:file branch2:file
  ```

  ***Example:***

  ```
   git diff branch1:full/path/to/foo.txt branch2:full/path/to/foo-another.txt
  ```
- Only if the name is the same and you want to compare your current working directory to some branch:

  ```
  git diff ..someBranch path/to/file
  ```

  ***Example:***

  ```
  git diff ..branch2 full/path/to/foo.txt
  ```

  > In this example you are comparing the file from your actual branch to
  >   the file in the master branch.

You can check this response:

[Compare a file from two different branchs in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49652444/3739382)

Comment: "Only if the name is the same and you want to compare your current working directory to some branch": This is misleading. It compares **the latest commit to the current branch"" to some other branch. Your wording implies that it will compare the file actually found on disk, if there are uncommitted changes; it's not so.

Answer (score -1):

You can specify a start and range for `git diff` to be applied to. The range is indicated with the `..` notation.

```
branch1=somebranch
branch2=someotherbranch
git diff ${branch1}..${branch2} -- file_path
```

Comment: This is only comparing the same file in two branches; the question was about two different files in two branches.

Comment: @Piran and I landed on this question because I wanted to compare the same file in two branches so I'm happy this answer exists.