# git diff between two different files

Tags: git, diff

In `HEAD` (the latest commit), I have a file named `foo`. In my current working tree, I renamed it to `bar`, and also edited it.

I want to `git diff` between `foo` in `HEAD`, and `bar` in my current working tree.

Comment: I thought this question (from the title) might be about using git diff on two files that aren't necessarily in a repo. I found that the --no-index flag is for that, e.g. `git diff --no-index --word-diff old_file.txt new_file.txt` (--word-diff highlights changes by word, not just line, which is super helpful for long text).

Comment: [Very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131135/git-how-to-diff-two-different-files-in-different-branches). This question focuses on when one file (at least) is in the working tree, and the other focuses on when both files have been committed.

Answer (score 264, accepted):

Specify the paths explicitly:

`git diff HEAD:full/path/to/foo full/path/to/bar`

Check out the `--find-renames` option in the `git-diff` [docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html).

Credit: [twaggs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131135/git-how-to-diff-two-different-files-in-different-branches).

`git diff <path> <path>` will compare two working-tree files as long as at least one of them is not in a git repo or the command is run from outside of a git repo. If you want to ensure git knows you are only comparing files in the working-tree (that is, on files in your directory rather than files added or commited to git), use `git diff --no-index <path> <path>`

Comment: I want to mention, that you could compare any two files using `git diff <path> <path>` even if they are not in a git repository.

Comment: @mitenka I don't think that's correct. If you look at `git diff --help` you'll see that the only patterns that are supported for two files is `git diff [<options>] --no-index [--] <path> <path>`. `git diff a b` only matches commit patterns, not files.

Comment: @Doug Here is the quote from help command you mentioned, https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff: Show [...] changes between two files on disk.

Comment: @mitenka the help says, unless you use '--no-index' it does not compare files; your comment should be a separate answer; it's not true and it's not relevant to this answer.

Comment: @Doug Thank you for your opinion. Here's the quote from help you reference to: You can omit the `--no-index` option when running the command in a working tree controlled by Git and at least one of the paths points outside the working tree, or when running the command outside a working tree controlled by Git.

Comment: What does the `HEAD:` signify? Also, is there way how to diff between files of two different branches?

Comment: using the above without the `HEAD:` worked for me

Comment: @mitenka So to "edit" your original comment (if that were allowed), we should say that `git diff <path> <path>` can be used, but **only** if at least one of the files is not in a git repo.

Comment: Good point @josiah-yoder. I can't edit comments tho ‍♂️

Comment: @mitenka But I now have queue-free priveleges, so I've added an edited version of the answer to the question itself. Now back to paying work.

Comment: I'm not enough of an expert to comment on your original intent in this answer. I'm a bit confused as to when your answer compares with the file tree. I'm certain you are naming a file in a commit/branch with the ':' syntax, but don't follow how this will compare with a file in the working tree.

Answer (score 294):

I believe using `--no-index` is what you're looking for:

```sh
git diff [<options>] --no-index [--] <path> <path>
```

as mentioned in the git manual:

> This form is to compare the given two paths on the filesystem. You can
>   **omit** the `--no-index` option when running the command in a working tree
>   controlled by Git and **at least one of the paths points outside** the
>   working tree, or when **running the command outside** a working tree
>   controlled by Git.

Comment: Quite helpful for leveraging git's powerful whitespace-insensitive "word diff" (eg: `git diff --no-index --word-diff file1 file2`), even for files that are not git-controlled. (At least for me on git v2.25.1, Ubuntu v20.04.)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using tortoise git you can right-click on a file and git a diff by:
Right-clicking on the first file and through the tortoisegit submenu select "Diff later"
Then on the second file you can also right-click on this, go to the tortoisegit submenu and then select "Diff with yourfilenamehere.txt"