# git diff differently-named files in different commits

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

In a recent refactoring, I split file `a.txt` into `b.txt` and `c.txt` in `branch1`, and split it into `c.txt` and `d.txt` in `branch2`. When diffing, Git interprets such a split as moving e.g. `a.txt` to `b.txt` (since they have more content in common) with changes, and adding `c.txt` as a new file.

**How can I `git diff` files with different names from different commits?** e.g. How can I diff these with each other?

- `b.txt` from `branch1`
- `d.txt` from `branch2`

Comment: does using `git diff -M3` give `git` enough hints to follow moves?

Comment: maybe this might help you with your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/16683184/8776411

Comment: @NiklasKlausberger yes, the 2nd option on the linked answer is what I was looking for. `git diff branch1:b.txt branch2:d.txt` in my example. (Except the linked answer doesn't specify both branches, as does the one it links to.) Thanks!