# Git diff between 2 different files on the same branch

Tags: git, git-diff

I have 2 different files `foo` and `bar`.

Each one is on 2 different commits, on the same branch, respectively with SHA1 `SHA1-foo` and `SHA1-bar`.
I want to see a diff between those 2 files.

I could checkout one of the files and copy it but maybe there's a better way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git diff commits difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191282/git-diff-commits-difference)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: How to diff two different files in different branches?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131135/git-how-to-diff-two-different-files-in-different-branches)

Comment: It's not the same as the commits difference, because I want 2 different files, not the same files.

Comment: The question with branches is similar, but here I want 2 different commits on the same branch instead of 2 different branches, see my answer.

Comment: It's the same syntax, obviously. What's the point in having a QA for any slight variation of the question ?

Comment: I didn't knew it was the same syntax. It wasn't obvious for me. Feel free to remove if you think it's needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that it works the same way as branches, see [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131135/git-how-to-diff-two-different-files-in-different-branches).

```
git diff SHA1-foo:/path/to/foo SHA1-bar:/path/to/bar
```

Comment: By the way you need to specify both branches otherwise it will not work. Git will not use your current branch as default.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
git diff branch1:file branch2:file
```

Comment: Yes that's the idea except that it's for different commits instead of different branches, but it seems to work the same way. See my answer.

Comment: Oh, I misread the question. Yeah, in that case you are correct.