# Compare foo.bar from two different branches in MAGIT

Tags: git, emacs, magit

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4099805/671013) shows how to see the differences between a specific file `foo.bar` in two different branches in `git`. My question is **how to do this within [`magit`](https://github.com/magit/magit)**?

Comment: You can always issue a git command from the magit status buffer by typing `:` (e.g.: `: diff mybranch master -- myfile.cs`)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I use magit to complement `vc`.  `vc` already has this functionality <kbd>C-u C-x v =</kbd>

Comment: Can you write what is the command issued for you with this bind?

Comment: Find out for your self.  <kbd>C-h k</kbd> <kbd>C-x esc esc</kbd>

Comment: Is there a way to add some (un)folding functionality to the resulting buffer? Like similar to the one available in `*magit-diff*` buffer.

Answer (score 7):

Just wanted to note that this is now directly possible with `magit`.

In the Magit status buffer, type `d` to open up the diff popup.

Then limit the diff to your file of interest with `=f` and the file name.

Finally, do a diff range `r` and type in the branch that you want to compare to (one can also type in a specific commit on the same branch, see [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43051793/3536806)).

Comment: or from the file buffer: `C-c M-g D r`

Comment: =f does not exist...

Comment: The shortcut has changed to `--`, is that also the case for you?

Answer (score 2):

Building up from @dominik-schrempf answer, it is also (now) possible to select the range of the diff with text selection to go quicker than typing the hashes of the commits.

So a quicker (and more visual) sequence could be :

0. Start from any Magit buffer with a list of commits 
   (like any commit log or the recent commits list in the Magit status buffer) :
1. Select the commits using text selection

   1a. Have the cursor on one end of the wanted commits

   1b. Toggle text selection `C-SPC` (or `V` if you use evil-mode)

   1c. Move your cursor over to the other end of the wanted commits
2. `d` to open the diff popup
3. `d` to open the dwim buffer or `r` for diff range  (They do mostly the same thing in this case, I think)

For the text selection part, it is the `set-mark-command` function of Emacs. 
You can learn more about it by using Emacs' integrated help system:

- `C-h f` followed `set-mark-command`, or;
- from the `execute-extended-command` 
  (which should be your second best friend after the help prefix key `C-h` seen above)
  `M-x` followed by `describe-function` followed by `set-mark-command`.

These two paths are equivalent as every Emacs keybindings is calling a function.

In short, use the help prefix and the `execute-extended-command` often, especially when starting using Emacs.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "Select the commits"? In the log, under Recent commits? I always see just the diff for the commit under the pointer.

Comment: Just added some more precise informations. ^^
Let me know if this answers your questions, and if I have some more modifications that could be helpful.

I'm not quite sure how to add more though without getting out of scope of the question, but more in-depth information about the non-magit emacs specifics can be found at (Mastering Emacs)[https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/mastering-key-bindings-emacs] and (Ergoemacs)[http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_esoteric.html]. 

Happy Hacking :)