# magit: how to diff the same file between two different commits on the same branch?

Tags: git, emacs, magit

How can I get the diff between two commits of the **same** file using `magit`?

Directly form `git` one can do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3338145/671013). But I don't know how to do it from within `magit`. From `magit-status` it seems that `d` and `D` returns the diff of the *whole* repository. This is very problematic for me as the repository is *huge* and it causes `magit` (and in turn `emacs`) to become unresponsive. Is there a way to ask `magit` to restrict the search to only one file from the repository?

I also tried, in the `magit-status` buffer to do `: diff $start_commit..$end_commit -- path/to/file`. This works, but the output is a simple buffer without any highlighting nor any folding options...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare foo.bar from two different branches in MAGIT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358936/compare-foo-bar-from-two-different-branches-in-magit) (given that branches are just named commits in git, these questions are the same.)

Answer (score 12):

In case anyone stumbles across this now, it is now possible to do this in magit (I do this from magit-log but you can probably do it from elsewhere, too):

1. Type `d` to open the magit-diff-popup
2. Type `=f` to specify the file you want to view (enter path relative to the project root dir)
3. Type `r` to do a diff range. You will be asked for the commit range, for example, `4abcde2..HEAD`. Alternately, if you highlight the range of commits in magit-log, the range will be set for you automatically with no prompt.

This way, you end up in a magit-diff buffer complete with highlighting and code folding.

Comment: Or with `magit-file-mode` enabled (probably by way of `global-magit-file-mode`), you can use `C-c M-g D r`. You can bind `magit-file-popup` to something easier to type than `C-c M-g` if that's too cumbersome.

Comment: `M-x magit-diff-popup` gets you there too.

Answer (score 5):

One way to go is to use `vc` as suggested by [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16363103/671013) - in particular <kbd>C-u C-x v =</kbd>. However, this return a buffer without the possibility to (un)fold chunks.

Answer (score 3):

Building up from @cdidyk answer, it is also (now) possible to select the range of the diff with text selection to go quicker than typing the hashes of the commits.

So a quicker (and more visual) sequence could be :

1. Select the commits using text selection `C-SPC` (or `V` if you use evil-mode)
2. `=f` to specify the file (path relative to the project root folder)
3. `d` to open the diff popup
4. `d` to open the dwim buffer or `r` for diff range  (They do mostly the same thing in this case, I think)

Answer (score 2):

You can also do `M-x` and `magit-ediff-compare`.

Then enter the SHA of the older commit and then the filename of the file you want to compare to `HEAD`, all on the same branch.