# Git - Is it possible to restore to the state before I resolve conflicts wrong

Tags: git, storyboard

When I rebase my local feature branch onto the develop branch, there were some conflicts.
So I need to resolve them, but this resolving is actually modify my commit.
So the question is what if the resolving is wrong (then, I've lost my correct code)? How do I restore to the previous state except back up that branch in advance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mention in "[Undoing a git rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134882/undoing-a-git-rebase)", you always can restore the branch as it was before the rebase with [`git reflog`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog), or, if you were just done with the rebase, [`ORIG_HEAD` (also HEAD@{1}](https://stackoverflow.com/a/967611/6309))

Even if you don't want to undo your rebase, but simply refer to the code as it was before the rebase, you can make a `tmp` branch where it was before said rebase:

```
git branch tmp @{1}
```

That allows you to [compare a file between your current branch and `tmp`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4099805/6309):

```
git diff tmp feature_branch -- myfile.cs
```

Comment: Your suggestion is great

Answer (score 2):

You're in luck, because git (mostly<sup>1</sup>) only adds *new* commits every time you do anything with commits.  The old ones are still in there, they just become harder to find.

Specifically, you had your local feature branch—let's call it `feat`—based on the remote development branch, which we can call `origin/devel`.  This means you had some set of commits 
"branching off" this `origin/devel`.  Let's draw that:

```
                 A - B - C   <-- feat
               /
...- o - o - *               <-- origin/devel
```

Here `A` through `C` are three commits you made, while the existing ones are mostly just labeled `o` here, except for the `*` that marks where the tip of `origin/devel` was when you started.

At some point, you did a `git fetch` (or `git pull --rebase`, which does a `git fetch`) and your git contacted whatever git you originally cloned from, to pick up new commits *they* made.  Let's say they made two new ones, and draw them in:

```
                 A - B - C   <-- feat
               /
...- o - o - * - o - x
```

The last thing `git fetch` usually<sup>2</sup> does before it's done (and `git pull --rebase` resumes, if that's how you did your `git fetch`) is to update the `origin/` branch-labels, so `origin/devel` now points to the new branch-tip:

```
                 A - B - C   <-- feat
               /
...- o - o - * - o - x       <-- origin/devel
```

What `git rebase` does, including when invoked by `git pull --rebase`, is simple to describe: it *copies* your original commits,<sup>3</sup> then moves *your* label.  The originals, before the copies are made, are still in there:

```
                 A - B - C   [see below for naming]
               /
...- o - o - * - o - x       <-- origin/devel
                       \
                         A' - B' - C'   <-- feat
```

The copies have the same changes with respect to their parent nodes that the originals had to their own parents.  That is, whatever you did between `*` and `A`, git tries to make the same changes to `x` to come up with `A'`.  Then, whatever you did between `A` and `B`, git tries to do the same thing to `A'` to get `B'`, and so on.

When git can't quite do these automatically, you get those merge conflicts.  (Even if git thinks it *can* do them automatically, you should check the results somehow, because git can get this wrong.)

You can look at your original branch—your original `A` through `C` commits, specifically—by using a name that refers to commit `C`.  The easiest one is `ORIG_HEAD`, which `git rebase` sets to point to `C` just before it moves your `feat` label to point to `C'`.  However, there is also the "reflog", which keeps track of which commit `feat` used to name.  You can view the `feat`-branch reflog with `git reflog show feat`.  You can also use `git log -g` (alternative spelling: `git log --walk-reflogs`).  The reflog generally lasts longer: 30 to 90 days, by default.  The `ORIG_HEAD` name is replaced by various other commands (`git merge` and `git cherry-pick` in addition to `git rebase`) so it's just meant for immediate corrections.

If you know in advance that you want to save your original branch, you can make a new name (a branch or tag name) to point to the tip of the branch as it stands now (in this case, to commit `C`), *before* running `git rebase`:

```
git branch save-feat feat
```

Or, as I sometimes do:

```
git branch -m feat feat-1
git checkout feat-1
git checkout -b feat-2
```

and only then:

```
git rebase ...
```

so that I now have two versions of my `feat`ure branch.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git will delete commits (and other unused repository objects), but only after they're truly un-referenced.  In particular, the reflog holds on to old commits for a month or three, unless you do something to delete the reflog (including deleting the branch).

<sup>2</sup>In newer git (post 1.8.5 or so), `git fetch` *always* updates; in older versions, `git pull` invokes it in a way that inhibits updating the `origin/branch` labels.

<sup>3</sup>Specifically, `git rebase` uses a series of `git cherry-pick` operations to copy each commit.  (Note that it also tries to skip commits that are no longer necessary, except when invoked interactively.  For instance, if your `A`-to-`B` change is exactly the same as something added to `origin/devel`, `git rebase` can simply skip over `B` entirely while copying, giving you just `A'` and `C'`.)

Comment: Wow! your answer could be organised into a blog, thanks!

Comment: Great answer! Should `git branch save-feat feat` have been `git branch feat save-feat`?

Comment: @holdenweb: no, the syntax is `git branch <name> [<value>]` to create the new branch `<name>`, and we want to create the `save-feat` name at this particular time. The optional `<value>` part is the commit hash ID to stuff into the new name; the default is whatever hash ID `HEAD` resolves to. Writing `feat` here resolves the existing name `feat` to the correct hash ID, then creates the new name.

Comment: Thanks - I now see the relevant command reference is `git branch [--track | --no-track] [-l] [-f] <branchname> [<start-point>]`. I had been confused by seeing `git branch (-m | -M) [<oldbranch>] <newbranch>` and assumed more than I should have.
`