# Correct way to compare same file in different branches

Tags: git, branch, diff

This question [How to compare files from two different branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099742/how-can-i-compare-files-from-two-different-branches) deals with the issue of comparing the same file in different branches, but several answers are given and all of them appear to have some caveat.

These are the ways presented:

```
1- git difftool mybranch master -- myfile.cs
```

(several people complain about this not working for them; it did in my case)

```
2- git difftool branch1:file branch2:file
```

(a comment says "*Using the colons is not really a great way*")

```
3- git difftool branch1 branch2 path/to/file
```

Which one is the recommended way?

Comment: 1 or 3, but I would always use '--' to separate arguments from path. (double-hyphen syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1192194/6309)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your options 1. and 3. are exactly the same, apart from the fact that using `--` disambiguates it as a path.

  This may be important when the path doesn't currently exist (in either branch or locally).
- Now, I don't know what's so bad about the colon notation. It's the most versatile, because you can even do

  ```
  git difftool branch1:file_name1.txt branch2:path/to/some_otherfilename.txt
  ```

---

If it's just about the typing involved (I guess this is what the commenter means with "not great") then:

```
git difftool {branch1,branch2}:file
```

Or even

```
git difftool branch{1,2}:file
```

Would do nicely in bash