# Show diffs between files in different branches and edit one of them

Tags: git, branch

I have two files in two different branches: `branch1:./path1/fileA.dat` and `branch2:./path2/fileB.dat`.

I want to compare these files with each other and edit one of them, say `fileA.dat`, according to the differences shown.

If I checkout branch `branch1` and use the command (as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17021188/1391441)):

```
git difftool branch1:./path1/fileA.dat branch2:./path2/fileB.dat
```

I am able to see the differences between these files (I use [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) as my difftool) but *both* are opened as temporary files so I can't really edit `fileA.dat` in `branch1` because the changes will be lost after I close Meld.

This is not what I would have expected, since if I use a very similar command to [compare the same file in these two branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27104753/1391441):

```
git difftool branch1 branch2 file.dat
```

I can edit it *and save the changes*.

Am I doing something wrong here or is this just how `git` behaves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not cool but it works.

First, do as you did

```
git difftool branch1:./path1/fileA.dat branch2:./path2/fileB.dat
```

Next, in Meld click 'Browse...' and select fileA.dat manually.

Then you can edit and save it.

Comment: You're absolutely right, this works perfectly. I still wonder why `git` doesn't do this by default though. I'll leave the question open a bit more to see if somebody else has a more "git" approach, else I'll mark your answer as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I also tried to find a difftool/meld option to do this but could not find. Hope someone has a perfect answer.