# How do I call git diff on the same file between 2 different local branches?

Tags: git, diff, git-branch, git-diff, working-directory

Is there a way to check the difference between the working directory in my current branch against the working directory of another branch in a specific file? For example, if I'm working in branch A on file 1, I want to compare the difference with file 1 on branch B.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare files from two different branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099742/how-to-compare-files-from-two-different-branches)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Use the git diff branch branch filename syntax:

```
git diff branchA branchB -- file.cs
```

put the two names of your branches and optionally use the `-- filename` option to specify one file! Good luck, let me know if you have issues.

Comment: I don't think you need the `--` portion, and you can diff more than one file or directory this way. If you don't pass anything, it shows the entire branch diff.

`git diff branchA branchB` - diff between branches on entire repo
`git diff branchA branchB file.cs` - diff on that 1 file
`git diff branchA branchB some/path/in/rep some/other/path` - diffs two directories

Answer (score 24):

The following will help if you want to compare different files in two branches

```
git diff develop:foo.txt master:bar.txt
```

Comment: This was helpful: I needed to compare files that had moved around in the linux source. 
`git diff linux-v4.1.10:sound/soc/davinci/davinci-mcasp.c linux-5.4.y:sound/soc/ti/davinci-mcasp.c` did the trick.

Answer (score 10):

Say you're on one branch, called `legacy`, and want to compare the file `build.gradle` to the same version on the `master` branch:

`git diff master build.gradle`