# How to compare same file in different branches in git (either with visualstudio or with tortoise git, or with Git UI)

Tags: git, visual-studio

I would like to compare a file in two branches before the merge. 
For example: I have 2 branched for my code, 1.Master, 2.userstoryBranch. there is a file called Users.cs 
Currently, I am working on userstoryBranch and modified something in Users.cs.
someone else is modified Users.cs file in another branch and committed and updated in Master branch. 
Now I need to merge from Master branch. before doing this, I would like to compare Users.cs of userstoryBranch with  Master branch file. 
Is there any facility to do this ? if yes, how can we do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Details of how to do this via the command line are here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099742/how-to-compare-files-from-two-different-branches I don't know about a visual UI but if there's a diff wizard it might follow the same principles.

Comment: Thank you Elliot