# How to open git diff of two files from different branch by Meld?

Tags: git, meld

As I have found in the question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4099805/5962966/

I can compare the files between two git branches by the following command, but How do I open the `diff` window in `Meld` and save the changes as well?

`git diff mybranch master -- myfile.cs`

Already tried but not working: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34119867/5962966

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I view 'git diff' output with my preferred diff tool/ viewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-my-preferred-diff-tool-viewer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `diff` with `difftool`

`git difftool mybranch master -- myfile.cs`

If you only have meld installed git should use it as the default difftool. Regardless it should also give a prompt showing which tools are compatible and how to set the tool you wish to use.

Comment: Can I merge the changes and save too ?

Comment: Not when comparing a `branch` to `master` if you want to diff with what is already in your directory you want `git difftool mybranch -- myfile.cs`

Otherwise `git difftool mybranch master -- myfile.cs` and peform a `Save As...`

Comment: Then any way I can compare, merge and then save ?

Comment: Use `File->Save As...`