# Is there a way to compare a file over all branches?

Tags: git, git-diff

I know I can use `git diff` to check for the difference of a certain file across two specified branches.
Can it be done for all branches in a single command?
Would it also include the deleted branches?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099742/how-to-compare-files-from-two-different-branches

Comment: @Flowkap it answers the question for just two branches, but that's not my question.

Comment: It certainly answers your first question. You can easily create a shell script to fetch all branch names and compare master with all of those by e.g. awk. Or a specified one against all others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can it be done for all branches in a single command?

No.

> Would it also include the deleted branches?

No.

It's important to realize that in one sense, Git doesn't really have *branches*.  (In several other senses, though, it does.)  What Git has are *branch names*.  They're not nearly as important as people might think at first, though they are certainly important.

What Git is really about is commits.  It's not about *files*, although commits contain files; and it's not about *branch names*, although branch names identify specific commits.  Git is all about *commits*.  When you run `git diff br1 br2`, you are telling Git to run a diff on two specific *commits*.

Every commit stores a full snapshot of all the files that Git knows about—or rather, knew about, at the time you, or whoever, made that commit.  That's the main data for each commit.  Each commit also stores some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself, such as who—name and email address—made the commit, when (date and time stamp), and why (their log message for the commit).

Commits are numbered, but the numbers are random-looking hash IDs, rather than simple counting numbers.  The hash IDs are actually entirely *non*-random, as they are cryptographic checksums of the data-and-metadata inside the commit.  Git finds the commits by their hash IDs: there is a big *object database* inside the repository, with objects being numbered by these hash IDs.  (Commits are one of four object types within this object database.)

Because the hash IDs *are* checksums, no part of any commit can ever be changed.  You mostly add *new* commits to a repository.  (Commits *can* be forgotten, but only under particular conditions.)

Each commit stores, as part of its metadata, the hash ID—or sometimes hash IDs, plural—of its immediate predecessor commits.  In this way, Git can start with the *last* commit (of some branch) and work backwards, one commit at a time:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Here `H` stands in for the hash ID of the *last* commit of some chain of commits.  Inside commit `H`, which Git can read out of the object database, there is the hash ID of earlier commit `G`.  That lets Git find `G` in the object database; inside that object there is the hash ID of earlier commit `F`.  That lets Git find `F`, which has another hash ID, and so on.  This *is* the history, in the Git repository.

But this leaves Git with a problem.  How will it quickly and easily find the hash ID of the *last* commit?  For instance, in the above, where will Git find hash ID `H`?

A *branch name* solves this problem.  Each name holds one (1) hash ID, which is, by definition, the *last* commit in the chain.  So if `master` holds hash ID `H`, we have:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

If there is another branch name, that other branch name holds the hash ID of some commit—maybe `H`, maybe `G` or `F`, or maybe some commit after `H`.  Perhaps `develop` holds the hash ID of some commit `I`, whose parent is `G`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I   <-- develop
```

So now the name `master` and the name `develop` each pick out one specific commit.

You can run `git diff` and give it raw hash IDs; or you can run it and give it branch names.  When you give it branch names, Git just looks up the names and finds the hash IDs, then runs the diff on the two hash IDs.

So:

> Is there a way to compare a file over all branches?

Yes: enumerate all the interesting commits, and then run `git diff` in whatever way you like.  For instance:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads
```

will print (to standard output) each branch name, in the short form (`master`, `develop`, etc., rather than as their full names, `refs/heads/master`, `refs/heads/develop`, etc.).

To compare the snapshot of a particular file in commit C1 to that in some commit C2, you would use:

```
git diff C1 C2 -- path/to/file
```

The *pathspec* argument after the `--` limits the diff to just that one file.  (The `--` itself is optional here; it's generally a good idea to use it out of habit, to avoid ambiguity when you get into more complicated `git diff` usage.)

If you want to compare the snapshot in (say) the commit identified by the name `master` to the snapshot in the commit identified by the name `develop`:

```
git diff master develop -- path/to/file
```

will do the job.  So if you want to compare, one at a time, the commit in `master` to the commit in each branch:

```
git for-each-ref ... |
    while read branch; do
        git diff master $branch -- path/to/file
    done
```

would do the trick, for instance.  Fill in the `for-each-ref` as seen above.

Note that `for-each-ref` will print `master`, so you'll be running one `git diff master master -- path/to/file`, which will literally compare the tip commit of `master` to itself.  The file will match, which means `git diff` will print nothing, but this *is* slightly wasteful.  If you don't like the wastefulness, add code to test whether `$branch` is `master` and if so, to skip the `git diff` step (but note that this test itself also adds a bit of compute work, which for every *other* name, is slightly wasteful: TANSTAAFL<sup>1</sup>).

---

<sup>1</sup>There Ain't No Such Thing As A Free Lunch