# How to compare two git branches to get the commit hash make the difference

Tags: git

[image]Context:
I have two branches A and B working parallel with together,
"git diff" or "git log" provide for me how many files have changed (the difference between two branches),
but, how can I get the commit to making the difference between two branches, commit on branch A or commit on branch B, and what is commit hash?

```
For example, a list of the file is different between two branch
Branch A                               Branch B
File1                                   File1
File2                                   File2
```

I want to get commit to make difference,
commit xxxxx on branch A change File1
commit yyyyy on branch B change File2

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking, would you mind elaborating? In particular, what do you mean when you ask about a "commit"? Are you interested in what command you can run to apply all commits från e.g. branch B on top of branch A?

Comment: "git log" comparing the commit differences between 2 branches,
and I want to know what is commit made this difference, commit on branch A or commit on branch B made the difference between two branches.

Comment: @Tom What do you mean by "commit differences" exactly? Commits are one thing, diffs are a different thing. If you want to know which commits on branch A, unavailable on branch B touched what files you can try: `git log --stat B..A`.

Comment: Do you mean you want to list all files changed in each commit on each of the branches? Is that what you mean with "make the difference".

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but I think `git log`, which you already mentioned, can help you.

There is an option/variant, namely `...`, to show the symmetric differences between 2 branches, see [the man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) for further information. A command to show the changing files then is:

```sh
git log --stat branchA...branchB
```

Comment: How can I detect branch B added the new line or branch A has removed this line when diff two branches, and what is git revision?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like below

```
git diff branch1 branch2 -- file1
```

for eg: `git diff master feature/xyz file1.java`

For more details ,please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/4099805/6309111