# What does "@@ -1 +1 @@" mean in Git's diff output?

Tags: git, diff

I've been collecting data from the information returned from

```
git diff <commitId>..<commitId>
```

and I ran into `@@ -1 +1 @@`

I can't figure out what that's telling me. I've searched a bit on Google but to no avail.

Comment: Can you describe what file results in such header?

Comment: @kworr that's kind of a silly question, any diff in unified format has range headers.

Comment: @YuvalAdam: actually diff unified format has more fields that should be filled like [-+]<position>,<lines> and here we have no changes displayed but this changes touch first line of the file.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

It's a unified diff hunk identifier. This is [documented](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/diffutils.html#Detailed-Unified) by GNU Diffutils.

> The unified output format starts with a two-line header, which looks like this:
>
> ```
> --- from-file from-file-modification-time
> +++ to-file to-file-modification-time
> ```
>
> The time stamp looks like `2002-02-21 23:30:39.942229878 -0800` to indicate the date, time with fractional seconds, and time zone. The fractional seconds are omitted on hosts that do not support fractional time stamps.
>
> You can change the header's content with the `--label=label` option; see See [Alternate Names](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/diffutils.html#Alternate-Names).
>
> Next come one or more hunks of differences; each hunk shows one area where the files differ. Unified format hunks look like this:
>
> ```
> @@ from-file-line-numbers to-file-line-numbers @@
>  line-from-either-file
>  line-from-either-file...
> ```
>
> If a hunk contains just one line, only its start line number appears. Otherwise its line numbers look like `start,count`. An empty hunk is considered to start at the line that follows the hunk.
>
> If a hunk and its context contain two or more lines, its line numbers look like `start,count`. Otherwise only its end line number appears. An empty hunk is considered to end at the line that precedes the hunk.
>
> The lines common to both files begin with a space character. The lines that actually differ between the two files have one of the following indicator characters in the left print column:
>
> - **+**
>     A line was added here to the first file.
> - **-**
>     A line was removed here from the first file.

Answer (score 102):

**Simple example analysis**

The format is basically the same the `diff -u` unified diff.

For instance consider:

```
diff -u <(seq -w 16) <(seq -w 16 | grep -Ev '^(02|03|14|15)$')
```

where:

- the first file contains `01`, `02` through `16`
- the second file contains the same but with lines `02`, `03`, `14` and `15` removed

Diff output:

```
@@ -1,6 +1,4 @@
 01
-02
-03
 04
 05
 06
@@ -11,6 +9,4 @@
 11
 12
 13
-14
-15
 16
```

`@@ -1,6 +1,4 @@` means:

- `-1,6` means that this piece of the first file starts at line 1 and shows a total of 6 lines. Therefore it shows lines 1 to 6.

  ```
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  ```

  `-` means "old", as we usually invoke it as `diff -u old new`.
- `+1,4` means that this piece of the second file starts at line 1 and shows a total of 4 lines. Therefore it shows lines 1 to 4.

  `+` means "new".

  We only have 4 lines instead of 6 because 2 lines were removed! The new hunk is just:

  ```
  01
  04
  05
  06
  ```

`@@ -11,6 +9,4 @@` for the second hunk is analogous:

- on the old file, we have 6 lines, starting at line 11 of the old file:

  ```
  11
  12
  13
  14
  15
  16
  ```
- on the new file, we have 4 lines, starting at line 9 of the new file:

  ```
  11
  12
  13
  16
  ```

  Note that line `11` is the 9th line of the new file because we have already removed 2 lines on the previous hunk: 2 and 3.

**Hunk header**

Depending on your git version and configuration, you can also get a code line next to the `@@` line, e.g. the `func1() {` in:

```
@@ -4,7 +4,6 @@ func1() {
```

This can also be obtained with the `-p` flag of plain `diff`.

Example: old file:

```
func1() {
    1;
    2;
    3;
    4;
    5;
    6;
    7;
    8;
    9;
}
```

If we remove line `6`, the diff shows:

```
@@ -4,7 +4,6 @@ func1() {
     3;
     4;
     5;
-    6;
     7;
     8;
     9;
```

Note that this is not the correct line for `func1`: it skipped lines `1` and `2`.

This awesome feature often tells exactly to which function or class each hunk belongs, which is very useful to interpret the diff.

How the algorithm to choose the header works exactly is discussed at: [Where does the excerpt in the git diff hunk header come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28111035/where-does-the-excerpt-in-the-git-diff-hunk-header-come-from)

**One line hunk summarized notation**

This is very rare, but consider:

```
diff -U0 <(seq -w 16) <(seq -w 16 | sed 's/10/hack/')
```

where:

- `-U0`: use 0 lines of context
- second file replaces `10` with `hack`

The diff output in that case is:

```
@@ -10 +10 @@
-10
+hack
```

So we understand that when there's a single line change, the notation gets summarized to showing just one number instead of the `m,n` pair.

This behavior is documented in the documentation quoted by [Todd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10950496/895245):

> If a hunk contains just one line, only its start line number appears. Otherwise its line numbers look like start,count. An empty hunk is considered to start at the line that follows the hunk.

And single line hunk addition and removal look like this, removal:

```
diff -U0  <(seq -w 16) <(seq -w 16 | grep -Ev '^(10)$')
```

output:

```
@@ -10 +9,0 @@
-10
```

addition:

```
$ diff -U0 <(seq -w 16 | grep -Ev '^(10)$') <(seq -w 16)
```

output:

```
@@ -9,0 +10 @@
+10
```

Tested on diff 3.8, Ubuntu 22.10.

Comment: Ah, so I would read `@@ -1,6 +1,4 @@` as "Starting at line 1, the old line count was 6 but the new line count is 4"

Comment: @Cloud yup that's it :-)

Comment: The question imvolves the elision of the line count in single-line hunks, which this answer does not address.

Comment: @fuzzyTew it does now

Comment: _For instance consider: `diff -u <(seq -w 16) <(seq -w 16 | grep -Ev '^(02|03|14|15)$')`_ What does this command do? What does it mean in relation to the text blocks in the other parts of your answer?

Comment: @aSemy 01 to 16 and 01 to 16 without 02, 03, 14, and 15 respectively. These should be easily deduced from the explanation of their first usage in the answer "where: the first file contains ..."

Answer (score 7):

It's the current hunk range information stating on which line numbers this diff hunk starts and ends.

Read [**http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Unified_format**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Unified_format) for an in-depth explanation.

Comment: Thanks. Helped out. When there is no trailing comma and s, it defaults to 1.