# Syntax error @@

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, syntax, syntax-error

I'm currently trying to compile nodejs for ARMv7l so i've followed this tuto:
http://fastr.github.io/articles/cross-compiling-node.js-for-arm.html

But when i do `./configure --without-ssl`
i've got this error:

```
/src/node-v0.1.104/deps/libev/wscript: error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/src/node-v0.1.104/tools/wafadmin/Utils.py", line 274, in load_module
    exec(compile(code, file_path, 'exec'), module.__dict__)
  File "/src/node-v0.1.104/deps/libev/wscript", line 3
    @@ -41,6 +41,7 @@ def configure(conf):
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: please add your code to the question

Comment: @WhatsThePoint: This is 3rd-party code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters he must have done something wrong for him to get this error

Comment: @@ is not part of the code. In the link you posted, the patch for `/libev/wscript` is the git diff.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "@@ -1 +1 @@" mean in Git's diff output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950412/what-does-1-1-mean-in-gits-diff-output)

Comment: git diff is it necessary to compile ?

Comment: I've never done it, but google `git apply`.

Comment: Right, cause i've not understand how patch wscript for arm

Comment: So, i've done a git apply of my patch wscript but same error still here, i've got syntaxerror on @@ when i launch ./configure command to configure nodejs before make, an idea ?