# What does 'multiline strings are different' meant by from RIDE (Robot Framework) output?

Tags: csv, selenium, robotframework

i am trying to compare two csv file data and followed below process in RIDE -

```
${csvA} =    Get File    ${filePathA}
${csvB} =    Get File    ${filePathB}
Should Be Equal As Strings    ${csvA}    ${csvB}
```

Here are my two csv contents -

**csvA data**

```
Harshil,45,8.03,DMJ
Divy,55,8,VVN
Parth,1,9,vvn
kjhjmb,44,0.5,bugg
```

**csvB data**

```
Harshil,45,8.03,DMJ
Divy,55,78,VVN
Parth,1,9,vvnbcb
acc,5,6,afafa
```

As few of the data is not in match, when i Run the code in RIDE, the result is FAIL. But in the log below data is shown -

**

```
Multiline strings are different:
--- first
+++ second
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
 Harshil,45,8.03,DMJ
-Divy,55,8,VVN
-Parth,1,9,vvn
-kjhjmb,44,0.5,bugg
+Divy,55,78,VVN
+Parth,1,9,vvnbcb
+acc,5,6,afafa**
```

I would like to know the meaning of ---first +++second @@-1,4+1,4@@ content.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When robot compares multiline strings (data that has newlines in it), it uses the standard unix tool `diff` to show the differences. Those characters are all part of what's called a *unified diff*. Even though you pass in raw data, it's treating the data as two files and showing the differences between the two in a format familiar to most programmers.

Here are two references to read more about the format:

- [What does "@@ -1 +1 @@" mean in Git's diff output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10950412/7432).  (stackoverflow)
- [the diff man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/diffutils.html#Detailed-Unified) (gnu.org)

In short, the `@@` gives you a reference for which line numbers are different, and the `+` and `-` show you which lines are different.

In your specific example it's telling you that three lines were different between the two strings: the line beginning with `Divy`, the line beginning with `Parth`, and the line beginning with `acc`. Since the line beginning with `Harshil` does not show a `+` or `-`, that means it was identical between the two strings.