# Git-gui show line numbers when viewing diff

Tags: git, git-gui

When I use Git-gui tool for making commits, I can look through the changes in edited files. But this utility does not display line numbers of changes in file, so it is hard to find these changes in editor then. Options menu displays git settings and no line number option is available. Is it possible to enable line numbers in Git-gui ?

Comment: I recommend checking out the git integrations in VS Code. See if they provide the features you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, **no**.

`git gui` does not feature that option.

You'd have to open your file in a proper editor software.

Comment: Or use a difftool like meld

Comment: Given the number of upvotes from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950412/what-does-1-1-mean-in-gits-diff-output), I believe it's worth mentioning here that the diff hunk identifier can be used to find the approximate line number.