# What meaning yellow diff in jest

Tags: jestjs, diff, git-diff

```js
test('transform', () => {
  const code = [
    ...
    '  write (i < 10) do',
    ...
  ].join('\n')

  expect(transform(code)).toBe([
    ...
    ' while (i < 10) { ',
    ...
  ].join('\n'))
})
```

[Image with yelloc diff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNLuA.png)

both line are identical for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mean a small diff, solution

```js
test('transform', () => {
  const code = [
    ...
    '  write (i < 10) do',
    ...
  ].join('\n')

  expect(transform(code)).toBe([
    ...
    ' while (i < 10) { ',
    ...
    ''
  ].join('\n'))
})
```

references
[What does "@@ -1 +1 @@" mean in Git's diff output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950412/what-does-1-1-mean-in-gits-diff-output/10950496)