# Can someone please help me make meaning of diff in git and svn

Tags: git, svn, diff

This is the output I get of the diff

```
diff --git a/README.md b/README.md
index cda48bc..95ce355 100644
--- a/README.md
+++ b/README.md
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 THIS IS LINE 1
-THIS IS LINE 2
+THIS IS LINE X
 THIS IS LINE 3
```

File in workspace looks like this

```
 THIS IS LINE 1
 THIS IS LINE X
 THIS IS LINE 3
```

File in staging looks like this

```
 THIS IS LINE 1
 THIS IS LINE 2
 THIS IS LINE 3
```

So what does the following mean... I really don't understand the diff output

```
diff --git a/README.md b/README.md
index cda48bc..95ce355 100644
--- a/README.md
+++ b/README.md
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 THIS IS LINE 1
-THIS IS LINE 2
+THIS IS LINE X
 THIS IS LINE 3
```

Comment: seriously? Why are you asking this again? You just asked this a few minutes ago!

Comment: I just dont get it so I made a better example sorry

Comment: Then you should use comment on the answers to your original question, and possibly expand your question, not post almost the exact same question a second time. There is also Google, which would have shown you that there are many pages that explain the unified diff format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format and meaning of a Unified Diff is explained well [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Unified_format)

Answer (score 2):

You can read it like this:

-THIS IS LINE 2

+THIS IS LINE X

In the first file, the line "THIS IS LINE 2" is not present, and it is replaced instead by "THIS IS LINE X."

Comment: that I got... sorry trying to understand "@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@"

Comment: this is explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558597/meta-line-in-svn-diff-or-git-diff.