# How can I recover the file I deleted in git

Tags: git, github

I am totally beginner to git. Now, my problem is I like to recover the file my friend deleted. I have the commit for it and it hasn't been pushed up yet. I have tried revert, rest, summary etc and they don't work for me. Help me out.

I don't remember the filename. So I like to know how to check the things done in a commit either. Please help me. Here is the commit's SHA

commit 0e3e0e85727f02ff1d23a42bdb994cb2ff7326dc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following command will show all the changes in this commit, including your file.

```
git show 0e3e0e85727f02ff1d23a42bdb994cb2ff7326dc
```

or check out the commit to a new branch, then you can find the file in branch tmp

```
git checkout 0e3e0e85727f02ff1d23a42bdb994cb2ff7326dc -b tmp
```

Comment: What does a/ and b/ mean?

Comment: And can u explain me about the color difference mean which are green and purple, I think. Thank u so much

Comment: green is added lines/files. red is deleted lines/files

Comment: The line start with '+' means this line is added line.The line start with '-' means this line is deleted line. check this https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Unified-Format.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility#Unified_format and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529441/how-to-read-the-output-from-git-diff

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset till last commit you can do:

```
git reset --hard <commitId>
```

example - `git reset --hard 0e3e0e85727f02ff1d23a42bdb994cb2ff7326dc`

This should be fine