# What does a Git diff "-" sign means

Tags: git

I am trying to find out what does the "-" mean in the git diff I get. 
It is not a new line because when I add a line I get a "+".

```
diff --git a/webapp/pom.xml b/webapp/pom.xml
index 73486d22a..a58a214c3 100755
--- a/webapp/pom.xml
+++ b/webapp/pom.xml
@@ -180,7 +180,6 @@
             <version>1.5.8</version>
         </dependency>
         -->
-
     </dependencies>

     <profiles>
```

Comment: That means that the empty line has been removed. You can remove the modification by checking out the file : `git checkout pom.xml`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read the output from git diff?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529441/how-to-read-the-output-from-git-diff)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-diff%5D+output+format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the line was removed in the newer file.

Excerpt from the [git diff documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#_combined_diff_format):

```
    A - character in the column N means that the line appears in fileN but it does 
    not appear in the result. A + character in the column N means that the line 
    appears in the result, and fileN does not have that line (in other words, the
    line was added, from the point of view of that parent).
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is details about the `git diff`

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff

Specified the character used to indicate new, old or context lines in the generated patch. Normally they are +, - and ' ' respectively.

Answer (score 0):

From the `git diff` manual

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff:

> A "combined diff" format looks like this:

```
diff --combined describe.c
index fabadb8,cc95eb0..4866510
--- a/describe.c
+++ b/describe.c
@@@ -98,20 -98,12 +98,20 @@@
    return (a_date > b_date) ? -1 : (a_date == b_date) ? 0 : 1;
  }

- static void describe(char *arg)
 -static void describe(struct commit *cmit, int last_one)
++static void describe(char *arg, int last_one)
  {
 +  unsigned char sha1[20];
 +  struct commit *cmit;
    struct commit_list *list;
    static int initialized = 0;
    struct commit_name *n;

 +  if (get_sha1(arg, sha1) < 0)
 +      usage(describe_usage);
 +  cmit = lookup_commit_reference(sha1);
 +  if (!cmit)
 +      usage(describe_usage);
 +
    if (!initialized) {
        initialized = 1;
        for_each_ref(get_name);
```

> It is followed by two-line from-file/to-file header

```
--- a/file
+++ b/file
```

> Similar to two-line header for traditional unified diff format, /dev/null is used to signal created or deleted files.

Comment: The example in the question is a regular diff, not a combined diff. (It probably would be useful if the Git documentation described a regular diff before diving into the combined diff format.)