# What does these numbers mean in GitHub commit page?

Tags: github

What does these numbers mean in the following GitHub screenshot?

[image: GitHub screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reviewing a diff, meaning there is deletion and addition. These chars shows how much exactly:

- `-21,13` says the deletion is located in the sample from line 21, 13 lines long
- `+21,20` says the addition is located in the sample from line 21, 20 lines long

In other words, this diff concern an addition of 7 new lines, or maybe an addition of 10 lines and a deletion of 3 lines, etc.

These lines are the usual output of `git diff` command. Complete explanation are already available on [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2530012/1887976)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've checked the link and get what I need. These numbers basically means the specific block of code's old version has 13 lines and this version has 20 lines. Not the deletion and addition, just quantity of lines:D