# In git diff, what do --- and +++ mean?

Tags: git, version-control

```
--- a/python3.py
+++ b/python3.py
```

That is what I got when running git diff and don't know what the meaning of `---` and `+++` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full output of a git diff is explained here [How to read the output from git diff?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529441/how-to-read-the-output-from-git-diff).

Kind regards, Tom

Comment: Thank you tom, unclear to a beginner though...

Comment: Ok this is to indicate filename changes --- means old file, +++ means new file.
In the example the file stays python3.py so only changes to the content.
In case of a creation the --- will be /dev/null if a deletion happends the +++ will point to /dev/null. Moving a file in git will result (in my case) in git diff as a delete and create.