How to display the line numbers of changed lines when using git log -p command
git log -p display what code has been changed. But it does not display the line numbers of the changes like in the IDE.
Question: How to display the line numbers of changed lines when using git log -p command

The output already includes indicators of which lines are affected. @@ -205,6 +206,7 @@ at the top of a change hunk in diff -u format means the line number was 205 in the old version and 206 in the new version, and the size of this hunk was 6 lines in the old versions and 7 in the new version. I guess you could write a simple script to write these numbers out into the output, though I personally feel it would do more harm than good.

@tripleee aaa indeed. thanks a lot :D

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2530012/7976758
